# Let $X:[a,b)\to\mathbb R^n$ be a $C^1$ curve whose velocity does not vanish on $(a,b)$. Is the reparametrization by arc length still $C^1$?

Tags: calculus, curves, parametrization

Let $X:[a,b)\to\mathbb R^n\ (a<b)$ be a $C^1$ curve whose velocity does not vanish on $(a,b)$ (but $X'(a)$ could be $0$). Let $\varphi:[a,b)\to\mathbb R$ be defined by
\begin{equation}
\varphi(t) = \int_a^t |X'(u)|\ du\text{.}
\end{equation}
Then $\varphi$ is a bijective function onto its image, which is an interval. Define
\begin{equation}
Y=X\circ\varphi^{-1}\text{.}
\end{equation}
Then is it true that $Y$ is $C^1$, or at least differentiable on the whole domain?

I know that $Y$ is $C^1$ on the interval excluding $0$ (the endpoint), but I don't know what happens at $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no.

Consider the example where $X\colon[0,b)\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is a smooth spiral $t\mapsto(\exp(-1/t^2)\cos(t^{-1}),\exp(-1/t^2)\sin(t^{-1}))$ for $t\neq 0$ and $X(0)=(0,0)$.  This $X$ is $C^1$, but the reparametrised curve does not have a one-sided derivative at $0$ --- the spiral doesn't have a tangent direction at the limit point origin.

Comment: Thanks! How do you find such function? Is there a theory behind it? Also, I have not yet checked that your example really works. There is too much to calculate. Is there an easy way of doing it?